# Select and get image name in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First I need to select one of these images, then i would show which image was selected(maybe with a boundingbox), and last i need to print in my page (at the bottom for example) the name of selected image.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>

    <body>

    <div>
    <img img src = "http://www.juventus.com/pics/layout/open-graph-fallback.jpg" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img img src = "http://okeskor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Prediksi-Skor-Real-Betis-vs-Real-Madrid-25-Januari-2016.jpg" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add what you have tried and what is not working.  Currently this is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can highlight which image is selected by adding a class to the clicked image and then applying CSS to that class. I'm not sure what you mean by "name of selected image," but assuming you mean the filename, you can grab the `src` attribute of the clicked image and use [substring()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [lastIndexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) to grab the filename from the image source.

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src'),
        filename = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
    $('img').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.selected-image span').text(filename);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  cursor:pointer;
}
  img.selected {
    border:5px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img img src = "http://www.juventus.com/pics/layout/open-graph-fallback.jpg" />
  <img img src = "http://okeskor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Prediksi-Skor-Real-Betis-vs-Real-Madrid-25-Januari-2016.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="selected-image">Selected: <span></span></div>
```